# How to start nodejs server from Firebase server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using a socketIO for real time feature in my app. So, I have a problem when i deployed my app to Firebase hosting. My problem is how to run "node filename.js" command to start nodejs server in Firebase hosting ? 
Thanks for any helping .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting only serves static content, or dynamic content served through [Cloud Functions integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

You can't take control of the socket layer with things like socketIO. But you can use Realtime Database to send messages back and forth between client and server.

Comment: Thank you for reply , Doug Stevenson . I just use a real time for sending data between client and server. It gets message from server and show it in client side. How can i do ?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question.  When you have a different question than the one you originally asked, please create a new one in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Haha, forgive me. My purpose is i want to create a real time comment feature in my app. Everything is fine in localhost. But , i must start nodeJS when i want to use it. I don't know how to do it in Firebase hosting .

Comment: Like I said, Firebase Hosting can't do that.  Use Realtime Database instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my life . (*-*)